# sencha touch ajax request called twice

Tags: javascript, ajax, sencha-touch-2

My Sencha Touch 2 app has several places where it makes an AJAX request on a button click. It's pretty standard stuff:

```
console.log('Saving Billing Item at' + strURL);
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: strURL,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (result, request) {
        var resultJson = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
        console.log('Response from Saving BillingItem:' + result.responseText);
        data = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
        if(data.ErrorMessage.indexOf("successfully") == -1) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error!', 'Error saving Billing Item:' + data.ErrorMessage);
        } else {
            Ext.StoreMgr.get('BillingItemList').load();
            Ext.ComponentManager.get('MainMenu').animateActiveItem(23, {
                type: 'slide',
                direction: 'right'
            }); //back to list
        }
        Ext.ComponentManager.get('BillingItemSaveButton').setDisabled(false);
    },
    failure: function (result, request) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error!', 'There was a problem while saving the Billing Item. Please check your input and try again.');
        Ext.ComponentManager.get('BillingItemSaveButton').setDisabled(false);
    }
});
```

However the request is being sent to the server TWICE.

-The tap event is definitely being fired only once!

-If I manually browse to the URL in strURL, the server-side function is only fired once, so it doesn't appear to be anything server side.

However (identical, apart from the url) ajax requests elsewhere in the app only fire once, and I can't see any difference!

How do I go about tracking this down?

Comment: How did you come to know that Ajax request is fired twice? Any o/p on console?

Comment: The service is called twice on the server, every time the app fires the event once.

Comment: I am also having same problem . Did you find any solution to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the behavior by putting redirection to doPost from doGet in my service such as:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
    System.out.println("In doGet");
    doPost(request,response);
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {      
    System.out.println("In doPost");
}
```

Result was:

```
In doPost
In doGet
In doPost
```

I remember something being only applicable in POST method in EXTJS but i cannot recall it right now. That being said, your servlet does not run twice, but runs both doGet and doPost.

Comment: I moved on from Sencha a long time ago, but thanks for the insight. Hopefully other will find it helpful.